# Do Bluetooth headphones compensate for the audio delay by slowing down the video?

Tags: audio, video, bluetooth, headphones, airpods

I've always wondered why the delay was so small (I'd say unnoticeable) when I'm using the Airpods, as opposed to other BT earphones. I've also noticed that when I open, say, a YouTube video, the picture stutters for a few milliseconds (seemingly out of sync with the audio) and then goes on in total sync from there. That doesn't seem to happen when I'm using a wired headset or built-in speakers.

This has lead me to wonder if the Airpods (or maybe something in the device's Bluetooth implementation) delay the picture slightly whenever the computer sees a BT headset so that the user doesn't notice the audio delay. If that is the case, then certain things, like gaming, get affected even more than I thought they are.